# Why would Harry and Ron go for human females?

Tags: harry-potter, romantic-interest

From *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*:

> ‘And now, without further ado, allow me to introduce …the Bulgarian Team Mascots!’
>
> The right-hand side of the stands, which was a solid block of scarlet, roared its approval.
>
> ‘I wonder what they’ve brought?’said Mr Weasley, leaning forwards in his seat. ‘Aaah!’ He suddenly whipped off his glasses and polished them hurriedly on his robes. ‘Veela!’
>
> ‘What are Veel–?
>
> ’But a hundred Veela were now gliding out onto the pitch, and Harry’s question was answered for him. **Veela were women …the most beautiful women Harry had ever seen …except that they weren’t –they couldn’t be –human. This puzzled Harry for a moment, while he tried to guess what exactly they could be; what could make their skin shine moon-bright like that, or their white-gold hair fan out behind them without wind** …but then the music started, and Harry stopped worrying about them not being human –in fact, he stopped worrying about anything at all.
>
> The Veela had started to dance, and Harry’s mind had gone completely and blissfully blank. **All that mattered in the world was that he kept watching the Veela, because if they stopped dancing, terrible things would happen...**
>
> And as the Veela danced faster and faster, wild, half-formed thoughts started chasing through Harry’s dazed mind. **He wanted to do something very impressive, right now. Jumping from the box into the stadium seemed a good idea …** but would it be good enough?
>
> ‘Harry, what are you doing?’said Hermione’s voice from a long way off.
>
> The music stopped. Harry blinked. He was standing up, and one of his legs was resting on the wall of the box. Next to him, Ron was frozen in an attitude that looked as though he was about to dive from a springboard.
>
> Angry yells were filling the stadium. The crowd didn’t want the Veela to go. Harry was with them; he would, of course, be supporting Bulgaria, and he wondered vaguely why he had a large green shamrock pinned to his chest. Ron, meanwhile, was absent-mindedly shredding the shamrocks on his hat. Mr Weasley, smiling slightly, leant over to Ron and tugged the hat out of his hands.
>
> ‘You’ll be wanting that,’he said, ‘once Ireland have had their say.’
>
> ‘Huh?’said Ron, staring open-mouthed at the Veela, who had now lined up along one side of the pitch.
>
> Hermione made a loud tutting noise. She reached up and pulled Harry back into his seat. ‘Honestly!’she said.

Harry and Ron were Gryffindors and they were brave enough to break rules of Hogwarts. So, they could surely break the rules of society to marry Veela (BTW, it never looked odd to me because there was already a half-Veela in the canon, meaning human and Veela are compatible in terms of reproduction, and such marriage had happened in the past).

Talking about emotions, anything happened after they saw Bulgarian Veela. Plus, when you are brave (ambitions etc start from bravery), emotions don't matter at all. I once dumped an awesome angel-type hot girl who was so much in love with me only because she didn't use to drive Ferrari, so I know the feeling.

Why didn't Harry and Ron go for Bulgarian Veela over human females?

Comment: Same reason I didn't go for any supermodels....

Comment: @DVK I don't know about you, but talking about the generic society, people often don't go for supermodels because they don't have a choice and they aren't ambitious enough. In case of Harry, he was famous (across entire Wizarding World) as well as ambitious, so he could easily get a Veela.

Comment: clearly false in canon. The only Veela we know who went for *anyone* who also knew Harry, went for Bill Weasley - NOT rich nor famous :)

Comment: @DVK Well, not completely true, her little sis (presumably as quarter-Veela as Fleur) had at least an interest in Harry. Admittedly it was more like a crush by a (by then a little more grown up) young girl, whose life he had saved (not *really* true in Gabrielle's case, but it felt that way). But of course we know that Harry doesn't go for that kind of girl... huh,... oh well...

Comment: Because they throw fire at people

Answer (score 28):

Probably a bunch of reasons:

1. **Romantic relationships are about more than just physical attraction.**
2. **The intense attraction they feel towards the Veelas is magically-induced.** Although Veela are certainly very naturally attractive (when they're not turning into fireball-throwing bird-people), the intense attraction described in the quote in the question is almost certainly the result of some kind of compulsive magic. I'm sure I remember this being explicitly referenced somewhere in the series, but I can no longer remember where; the following quote from *Goblet of Fire* will have to do (emphasis mine):

   > "She's part veela," said Harry. "You were right - her grandmother was one. It wasn't your fault, **I bet you just walked past when she was turning on the old charm** for Diggory and got a blast of it
   >
   > <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 22: "The Unexpected Task"</sup>
3. **Harry is pretty consistently crushing on other girls.** He spends basically all of *Goblet of Fire* and the first two-thirds or so of *Order of the Phoenix* on a Cho Chang bend, and from *Half-Blood Prince* onward he's firmly devoted to Ginny. Why, exactly, would he be pursuing Veela (see point 1)?
4. **Ron lacks confidence, and is also interested in other girls.** To his credit, he did at least attempt to ask out a (part) Veela once. It went about as well as you'd expect:

   > "He - er - just asked Fleur Delacour to go to the ball with him," said Ginny. She looked as though she was fighting back a smile, but she kept patting Ron’s arm sympathetically.
   >
   > "You what?" said Harry.
   >
   > "I don't know what made me do it!" Ron gasped again. "What was I playing at? There were people - all around - I've gone mad - everyone watching! I was just walking past her in the entrance hall - she was standing there talking to Diggory - and it sort of came over me - and I asked her!"
   >
   > Ron moaned and put his face in his hands. He kept talking, though the words were barely distinguishable.
   >
   > "She looked at me like I was a sea slug or something. Didn't even answer. And then - I dunno - I just sort of came to my senses and ran for it."
   >
   > <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 22: "The Unexpected Task"</sup>

   Even without Ron's well-known inferiority complex, that's a pretty damaging ego blow, which would put a serious damper on any future attempts to woo a Veela. And, of course, at some point after this he starts being actively interested in Hermione, which ties back into my last point.

Answer (score 20):

When the veela are not casting their brain-washing skills we see that they are actually not very beautiful:

> The leprechauns had risen into the air again, and this time, they
>   formed a giant hand, which was making a very rude sign indeed at the
>   veela across the field. At this, the veela lost control. Instead of
>   dancing, they launched themselves across the field and began throwing
>   what seemed to be handfuls of fire at the leprechauns. Watching
>   through his Omnioculars, Harry saw that they didn't look remotely
>   beautiful now. **On the contrary, their faces were elongating into
>   sharp, cruel-beaked bird heads, and long, scaly wings were bursting
>   from their shoulders** -"

Seeing this, it would be quite normal that Ron and Harry prefer human girls.