# Was Harry ever attracted to anyone other than Ginny or Cho?

Tags: harry-potter, love

We know that Harry has crushes upon both Ginny and Cho at various points in the books. However, is there any canon evidence of him showing any form of attraction whatsoever to anyone else at any point?

Comment: He *really* fancied that broom.

Comment: what kind of attraction are you looking for, noticing looks, or a more serious one.

Comment: @Himarm, Yes, anything from a (as you put it) noticing looks upwards. I was wondering if he'd shown any interest in anyone else really, however fleeting that interest turned out to be.

Comment: Harry was a teenage boy. Part of being one of those is that you are sorting out who you are attracted to. It can vary on a weekly basis during adolescence.

Comment: Does Moaning Myrtle count?  She certainly made him... uncomfortable that time in the bath.  It's actually the most compromising scene in the entire series for him.  (Yes, he and Ginny had a kid, but that all happened off-page/screen between the last battle and the epilogue, so we never got to read/see it.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I think it's entirely possible that SHE may have had a crush on Harry. She certainly seemed hurt in the scene you mention that he hadn't been to visit her recently. She also said that if he died that he could share her toilet(!). I think that Harry's reaction in the bathroom is sheer awkwardness since he's naked and not expecting to be disturbed. There are many reasons why Harry wouldn't be attracted to Myrtle: one being that she's a ghost and another being that she's always crying (which, as we know from Cho, Harry finds offputting).

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Oh, I think her attraction to him was without question.  Still, judging by the awkwardness with which he got out of that tub, I'm pretty sure it's implied she had at least *some* effect on him, if only on a purely physical level, as I'm sure it would on most straight teenage boys caught naked in a tub by a reasonably attractive (albeit ethereal) girl.  (At least she's not a paving stone like in that one Doctor Who episode she was in...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman. I'm pretty sure he just wanted her to leave him alone, albeit he eventually recognised that she could be useful in helping him solve the egg clue. "Myrtle," Harry said **in outrage**. "I'm-I'm not wearing anything!".

Comment: FWIW I recall a tweet or something by Rowling about how she felt a little guilty because she felt that Harry probably should've ended up with Hermione rather than someone else.

Comment: @TylerH Shoulda coulda woulda. You're referring to her having second thoughts over pairing Ron and Hermione. Though I'm ignoring JKR in this instance as I think they make a great couple.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Well I'd like to refrain from suggesting I'm referring to something else unless there's a source you can provide that jogs my memory for clarification's sake, but I think Harry and Hermione should've been together even though her chemistry with Ron was OK.

Comment: @TylerH This is the link to what I'm thinking of. [link](http://www.cinemablend.com/pop/What-J-K-Rowling-Actually-Said-About-Hermione-Relationships-With-Ron-Harry-62153.html). Sorry if it wasn't what you were thinking of!

Comment: @TheDarkLord I think that is what I was thinking of, thanks for the link

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I don't think not wanting a creepy ghost girl to see you naked implies that Harry had any sort of crush or attraction to Myrtle, or that there was any kind of "physical reaction" to her being there. She's also never described as reasonably attractive in the books, is she? I always got the impression that she was meant to be the total opposite.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman yeah, I don't think so. She basically sexually harrassed him, from which I think it would be very bad to conclude that *he* was into *her*.

Comment: Hormones, hormones, hormones!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On several occasions, Harry describes [Madame Rosmerta](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rosmerta), the landlady at the Three Broomsticks as being *"pretty*" as well as noting her *[curvaceousness](https://media.giphy.com/media/mEXqNp4c7sWTS/giphy.gif)*

> It was extremely crowded, noisy, warm and smoky. **A curvy sort of woman
> with a pretty face was serving a bunch of rowdy warlocks up at the
> bar.** -
>
> <sup><sub>HP:PoA</sub></sup>

and

> **Madam Rosmerta, the
> pretty landlady, didn’t seem to think much of this;** she was looking
> askance at Moody as she collected glasses from tables around them
>
> <sup><sub>HP:GoF</sub></sup>

and

> ‘Nothing,’ said Ron, hastily looking away from the bar, but Harry knew
> he was trying to catch the eye of **the curvy and attractive barmaid,
> Madam Rosmerta, for whom he had long nursed a soft spot.**
>
> <sup><sub>HP:HBP</sub></sup>

---

He also noted that [Parvati](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Parvati_Patil) was not unattractive

> The common room looked strange, full of people wearing different
> colours instead of the usual mass of black. **Parvati was waiting for
> Harry at the foot of the stairs. She looked very pretty indeed,** in
> robes of shocking pink, with her long dark plait braided with gold,
> and gold bracelets glimmering at her wrists. Harry was relieved to see
> that she wasn’t giggling.
>
> <sup><sub>HP:GoF</sub></sup>

and nor was her identical twin [Padma](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Padma_Patil)

> **‘Hi,’ said Padma, who was looking just as pretty as Parvati in robes
> of bright turquoise.** She didn’t look too enthusiastic about having Ron
> as a partner, though; her dark eyes lingered on the frayed neck and
> sleeves of his dress robes as she looked him up and down.
>
> <sup><sub>HP:GoF</sub></sup>

He also managed to finally notice that [Hermione](http://lylian.info/images2/yule-ball-dresses/yule-ball-dresses-72.jpg) was kinda attractive, in the right light, with her hair done up.

> The oak front doors opened, and everyone turned to look as the
> Durmstrang students entered with Professor Karkaroff. **Krum was at the
> front of the party, accompanied by a pretty girl in blue robes Harry
> didn’t know**
>
> <sup><sub>HP:GoF</sub></sup>

Comment: There's a difference between being attracted to someone and thinking they're pretty. A guy might recognise that his sister or daughter is pretty without being attracted to them. The difference is slim, but perhaps it's worth also mentioning whether he actually *felt* attraction rather than admitting they're attractive.

Comment: Simply noting a person's physical attributes certainly doesn't mean they are *sexually* attracted to that person. Heck, I can look at a fit celebrity and acknowledge their physical attractiveness -- which, of course, is completely subjective -- and then move along without a second thought. Your quotes, I think, while demonstrating Harry noted the physical attributes of some of the female characters, read to me as more filler than a true show of Harry being attracted to a female other than Cho or Ginny. :)

Comment: @slytherincess - I'm reasonably certain that the question doesn't ask about sexual attraction.

Comment: @Slytherincess The quote from HBP does show that Harry had a "soft spot" for Rosmerta (who I'd forgotten about so credit to Richard for thinking of her). I think it's fair to say that Harry may not be hopelessly infatuated but isn't entirely apathetic towards her either. I suspect Harry and Ron weren't unique in having schoolboy crushes on the attractive barmaid during Hogsmeade visits. It may be subjective but it seems that Rosmerta appears in more than a 'she's curvaceous, moving on' sense.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - Trying to catch the eye of the landlady, and being relieved to see Parvati wasn't giggling at him immediately after noting she looked "very pretty indeed", both suggest something more than just a detached aesthetic observation that they were is pretty without personally feeling attracted to them. With Padma and Hermione the quotes don't as strongly hint at attraction though (but unless he knew Parvati and Padma well personally, it's likely that being attracted to one member of a pair of identical twins would imply being attracted to the other).

Comment: @TheDarkLord The quote from HBP is ambiguous, but I'd say that the "he" who has the soft spot for Rosmerta was Ron, rather than Harry, and it is the explanation as to why Ron was trying to catch her eye. (That said, Harry could have a soft spot for her too.)

Comment: @R.M. - Whenever Harry thinks about her, her always mentions how pretty she is and how curvy she is. I think we can assume that he's the one with the mini-crush.

Comment: @R.M. I think you're correct that it's Ron who the passage is referring to in this instance. As I say, though, I think that Harry too found her attractive and I suspect he wasn't the only Hogwarts teenager to do so.

Comment: I agree with @R.M., it is Ron who has the soft spot here; it had shown previously. E.g., the first quote (from PoA) continues as follows: *‘That’s Madam Rosmerta,’ said Ron. ‘I’ll get the drinks, shall I?’ he added, going slightly red.*

Comment: Uhm, I'm not that much into writing and therefor may be lacking of some knwoledge. Buuuuut... Aren't all the cites given for the arguments on Rosmerta phrases of the narrator? (which as far I remember wasn't Harry) So therefor the narrator noting physical attributes has simply no merit about the way each individual character perceives it, has it?

Comment: @Zaibis: Yes and no. The narrator isn’t Harry, but uses _internal focalization_ through Harry, most of the time (the exception are the introductory chapters in some of the books where a different focalization is chosen). So it is Harry’s perception that is described by the narrator.

Comment: @chirlu - Precisely this. If you look at my answer about [Harry's dislike of Slytherin House](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94247/20774), you can see it a lot more clearly.

Comment: @Slytherincess `Simply noting a person's physical attributes certainly doesn't mean they are sexually attracted to that person` Oh my sweet summer child; you don't know us men very well then :p

Comment: But this isn't told from the POV of Harry. So these are Joanna's descriptions, not Harry's...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - Rowling alternates between ***Third-person, omniscient*** and ***Third-person, subjective***, but never have we seen her express an opinion that isn't shared by Harry.

Comment: @Valorum - My point is, this isn't narrated by Harry so these aren't specifically his opinions and we _can't know for sure_ that she never expresses opinions that aren't shared by Harry. Finally, your quotes seem to be **descriptions** rather than **opinions**. It's important to notice the distinction...

Comment: Some of the examples you've given could be considered to be simply narration from the book; the author may be highlighting the fact that a particular barmaid is curvaceous and pretty to highlight the stereotype. This can be reinforced by third person omniscient viewpoint.  It could, of course, be down to the fact that you've provided limited detail in the snippets from the texts. The second piece sounds more like third person subjective with Moody being the subjective aspect.

Comment: @Paul - I've picked examples that I think highlight Harry's internalisation, rather than just the narrator giving us exposition about what's happening. If you scroll up the comments, you'll see (however) that you're not the first to say this.

Answer (score 51):

Harry was physically/magically attracted towards the Veela.

> Veela were women ... the most beautiful women Harry had ever seen ... except that they weren’t – they couldn’t be – human. The Veela had started to dance, and Harry’s mind had gone completely and blissfully blank. All that mattered in the world was that he kept watching the Veela, because if they stopped dancing, terrible things would happen ...

Harry clearly also finds Fleur attractive.

> A young woman was standing in the doorway, a woman of such breathtaking beauty that the room seemed to have become strangely airless. She was tall and willowy with long blonde hair and appeared to emanate a faint, silvery glow. To complete this vision of perfection, she was carrying a heavily
>   laden breakfast tray...

And he blushed when kissed by her in *The Goblet of Fire* (although to be fair it was in public by a girl he hardly knew).

> Fleur bent down, kissed Harry twice on each cheek (he felt
>   his face burn and wouldn’t have been surprised if steam was
>   coming out of his ears again),

In the "movies" he finds this waitress attractive:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114996/31394

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Waitress_at_Treats

Answer (score 1):

When Hermione warned Harry that Romilda Vane had crush on Harry, he enjoyed that.

This can be counted as attraction.

Comment: There's no indication that the attraction was reciprocated.

Comment: @Valorum I am definitely talking about Harry's attraction. Watch the video.

Answer (score 0):

### Moaning Myrtle

The 2001 edition of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* included a note from Ron teasing that Harry was in love with Moaning Myrtle. It would be just that, but however we also see that Harry tried crossing it out. [According to standard playground rules](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=playground%20rules), crossing out a note only indicates that it's true.

> [image]
>
> **Harry
>
> loves
>
> <strike>moaning</strike>
>
> <strike>myrtle</strike>**

It should be noted that, like all of Harry's and Ron's annotations, [this no longer appears in the new 2017 edition of the book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/166859/55866).

Comment: Pretty sure this is backwards - it's Myrtle who has a thing for Harry. Given Myrtles reputation, "Harry loves moaning Myrtle" is probably meant as more of a teasing insult.

Comment: Nice theory, but I agree with DavidS - Ron's teasing because she has a thing for him, not vice versa. I don't think the fact he crossed it out indicates it's true.

Comment: I've locked this answer to prevent an edit war whilst its content is under dispute and [moved the comments to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126949/discussion-on-answer-by-ibid-was-harry-ever-attracted-to-anyone-other-than-ginny) so that discussion can continue there if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

In Book 7, when Harry is in Luna Lovegood's room and he sees the artwork she made of him and his friends, Rowling writes that he **"felt a great rush of affection for Luna"** (DH, Chapter 7, p. 417 [American paperback edition]). This is a case of attraction based on emotion rather than physical attractiveness - and it could just be friendly affection, rather than a desire to date Luna, especially since Harry and Ginny are already an established couple at this point in the books.

Still, I think that one moment fits the bill for what this question was asking about. I have often wondered what might have happened between Harry and Luna if this scene had occurred earlier in the books - would it have sparked a romance? Alas, we can only speculate.

Comment: I think that it's more likely that this was more social affection than attraction, I'm afraid. Harry was touched by Luna's loyalty, nothing more. Remember that the artwork said 'Friends' and featured five people, not just Harry.

Answer (score -1):

### Edit to clarify in light of lengthy discussion in comments

This answer is based on two premises:

1. The narration is from Harry's point of view. Thus, descriptions of characters are in fact Harry's subjective perception of those characters.
2. Harry thinking that a girl is pretty does not in fact mean that he is personally attracted to her. However, per [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125731/was-harry-ever-attracted-to-anyone-other-than-ginny-or-cho#comment313833_125731) the question is seeking *anything from a (as you put it) noticing looks upwards. I was wondering if he'd shown any interest in anyone else really, however fleeting that interest turned out to be.*

---

### Original answer

In addition to the characters mentioned in the other answers, there are a bunch of females whom Harry considers pretty throughout the last three books of the series:

- **Roger Davies's girlfriend**

  > Roger Davies, the Ravenclaw Quidditch Captain, was sitting about a foot and a half away with a pretty blonde girl.
- **Statue of the witch in the Ministry of Magic**

  > A group of golden statues, larger than life-size, stood in the middle of a circular pool. Tallest of them all was a noble-looking wizard with his wand pointing straight up in the air. Grouped around him were a beautiful witch, a centaur, a goblin, and a house-elf.
- **Tom Riddle Sr.'s girlfriend**

  > Both he and the pretty girl riding beside him on a gray horse roared with laughter at the sight of Ogden, who bounced off the horse’s flank and set off again, his frock coat flying, covered from head to foot in dust, running pell-mell up the lane.
- **Lilly Potter**

  > She was pointing at the war memorial. As they had passed it, it had transformed. Instead of an obelisk covered in names, there was a statue of three people: a man with untidy hair and glasses, a woman with long hair and a kind, pretty face, and a baby boy sitting in his mother’s arms.
- **French wedding guests**

  > “Not so fast, Your Holeyness,” said Fred, and darting past the gaggle of middle-aged witches heading the procession, he said, “Here — permettez-moi to assister vous,” to a pair of pretty French girls, who giggled and allowed him to escort them inside.
- **Mrs. Delacour**

  > The first sound of their approach was an unusually high-pitched laugh, which turned out to be coming from Mr. Weasley, who appeared at the gate moments later, laden with luggage and leading a beautiful blonde woman in long, leaf-green robes, who could only be Fleur’s mother.
- **Horcrux version of Hermione**

  > “Presumption!” echoed the Riddle-Hermione, who was more beautiful and yet more terrible than the real Hermione: She swayed, cackling, before Ron, who looked horrified yet transfixed, the sword hanging pointlessly at his side.
- **Rowena Ravenclaw**

  > Harry recognized Rowena Ravenclaw from the bust he had seen at Luna’s house. The statue stood beside a door that led, he guessed, to dormitories above. He strode right up to the marble woman, and she seemed to look back at him with a quizzical half smile on her face, beautiful yet slightly intimidating.
- **Helena Ravenclaw**

  > She consented to pause, floating a few inches from the ground. Harry supposed that she was beautiful, with her waist-length hair and floor-length cloak, but she also looked haughty and proud.

Comment: Several of these are being described as attractive by the omniscient narrator, rather than from Harry's perspective.

Comment: @Valorum Any reason to think the narrator isn't Harry's perspective?

Comment: Note also, the fact that they're "pretty" or "beautiful" doesn't necessarily imply that Harry is attracted *to them*. I can't imagine Harry having lust in his heart for Fleur's mum.

Comment: @Valorum You're absolutely right, but the same argument also invalidates *your* answer (up above, score +30 currently). Characters being described as pretty or beautiful doesn't at all mean the main/viewpoint character is attracted to them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126928/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-was-harry-ever-attracted-to-anyone-other-than-ginny).